# caliburn.micro data transfer

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

I Have following Viewmodels in my WPF application.

```
CustomerViewModel
OrderViewModel
```

The application is implemented as a multi tabbed interface using `Conductor.Collection.OneActive` method.

The customer record is consist of an order record.
I need to open a new order screen from customer screen by clicking a context menu.

Simply I need to open a new order window from customer window.

I have initialized an instance of `OrderViewModel` inside `CustomerViewModel` and activated it.
But the new screen is opened but I cannot see any data on it.

How can I transfer data from `CustomerViewModel` to `CustomerOrderViewModel` while creating a new window in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

you can use INavigationService for this

```
public class SecondPageViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
  public string Title { get; set; }

  public SecondPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
  {
    Title = "Second Page";
  }
}

public void GoToSecondPage()
{
  navigationService.UriFor<SecondPageViewModel>().WithParam(l=>l.Title, "Navigated from MainViewModel").Navigate();
}
```

you can find sample code links hear :
[Navigation with parameters](http://blog.kulman.sk/developing-windows-store-apps-with-caliburn-micro-part-2-navigation/)

[page navigation and passing complex state](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/12/04/RealWorldWPDev-Part-6-Page-Navigation-and-passing-Complex-State.aspx)